# Why does adding new values to existing Key in Hashmap concatenates the values but only if it's done in a loop

Tags: .net, powershell, hashmap

My goal is to read a config file looking like this:

```
#This is a comment and ignored
[Section, gets ignored too]
key=value
animal=cat, dog
path="C:\Programm Files\", "C:\New Folder"
foo=bar
```

I want to put the values into a hashmap, where the value is a List looking like this

```
Name                Value
---                 ---
key                 {value}
animal              {cat, dog}
path                {"C:\Programm Files\", "C:\New Folder"}
foo                 {bar}
```

My code runs fine, however, it doesn't add dog or "C:\New Folder" as a second value but adds it as a concatenation. Adding the values in the console does work however:

```
$fileContent.animal.Count
>>1

$fileContent.path.Count
>>1

$fileContent
>>Name                Value
---                 ---
key                 {value}
animal              {cat dog}
path                {"C:\Programm Files\" "C:\New Folder"}
foo                 {bar}

$fileContent.path.Add("Test")
$fileContent.path.Count
>> 2
$fileContent
>>Name                Value
---                 ---
path                {"C:\Programm Files\" "C:\New Folder", Test}
```

My Code looks like this

```
foreach ($line in $fileRawContent)
{
    #if it doesn't start with # or [ continiue
    if(-not ($line.StartsWith("#") -or $line.StartsWith("[")))
    {          
        #Split string. Key always is on Position 0
        $content = $line.Split("=")
        $key = $content[0]

        #If Values with ',' are present, split again
        if($content[1].Contains(","))
        {
            $content = $content.Split(",")
            #$content = $content.Trim()
            
            #Add the contents to the values
            for($i = 1; $i -lt $content.Count; $i++)
             {
                    $value += $content[$i]
             }
        }
        #if no comma is present, it's a 1:1 link
        else {$value = $content[1]}

        #generate List on the key value
        $fileContent.$key = [System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]::new()

        #if only one value is present no running through an array is neccessary
        if($value.GetType().Name -eq "String")
        {
            $fileContent.$key.Add($value)
        }
        else
        {
            foreach($item in $value)
            {
                $fileContent.$key.Add($item)
            }
        }
    }

    #setting everything on null since the scope of powershell variables is global
    $content = $null
    $key = $null
    $value = $null
}
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: `$anUnassignedVariable += $someString` <- results in `$anUnassignedVariable` becoming a string. Make sure you initialize `$value` as an array (`@()`)

Comment: You're right. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps.  It will create an array for any element containing multiple values and add each to an object called foo.

1. Create an object to contain the data.  I'm using a GLOBAL to make it easier to call $foo at the command line after the script runs.

.

```
$GLOBAL:foo = @{}

$fileContents = gc -Path .\dale.txt
foreach($row in $fileC) {
      $propertyName,$propertyValue = $row

      # Converts to an array if contains comma separated string
      $propertyValue = $propertyValue.Split(",").trim()        
      $foo.$propertyName = $propertyValue
}
```

Run the script and then type $foo to see the object contents
$foo.Animal.GetType() will be an array along with Path.  All other values will be strings

Comment: Simply adding a `$value=@()` before the for-loop fixed the issue as @Mathias suggested in the comments under the question. But thank you :)